# Подскажите API URL геосервиса определения региона по IP адресу посетителя сайта

Tags: php, геолокация

Знаю про sypexGeo и IPgeobase. При этом в одном из проектов помню использовал API сервиса для определения георгафии пользователя по IP адресу который на мой взгляд лучше работал чем названные мной другие 2 сервиса.

Поскольку у меня уже нет доступа к тому проекту, не получается вспомнить что за сервис. Помню что в URL адресе сервиса присутствовало слово "Плагин" и скорее всего домен был в зоне NET. Может быть кто то знает что за сервис, скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на API если есть возможность.

Или если у этого сервиса есть библиотека на PHP (для применения без фреймворков и CMS) то тоже ссылочку и на неё.

Comment: ipwhois посмотрите

Comment: Тоже не он. ipwhois я про него знаю. Есть ещё какой то геоплагин(домен какой то такой) или как то так. Он близко к sypexgeo по информации. Только с теми Российскими IP адресами, что sypex определить не может вот то API про которое я говорю может справляться.

Comment: Может geoplugin.com?

Comment: Да! То что нужно. Вообще мне вот этот JSON api адрес был нужен: http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=88.85.173.110 Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Видимо то, о чем вы говорите - [geoplugin.com](https://geoplugin.com).

geoPlugin - это самый простой способ геолокации посетителей, позволяющий предоставлять геолокационный контент, более соответствующий их географическому положению. Простыми примерами являются перенаправление посетителей на страницы с определенным языком, предоставление цен на ваши продукты в местной валюте посетителя, знание того, применяются ли европейские правила конфиденциальности GDPR, и многое другое.